# Question on Spinor choice in QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wavefunction, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics, spinors

In QED (see Peskin and Schoeder's book on QFT or Srednicki's book), to determine the fermion wave-function, we usually start with a spinor of a massive particle that is not moving, say
$$u_+(\vec{p}=\vec{0})=\sqrt{m}\pmatrix{1\\0\\1\\0},\ \text{spin along $\hat{z}$ direction}\tag{1}\label{1}$$
and we perform a boost on that spinor, i.e.
$$u_+(\vec{p})=\exp(i\eta\hat{p}\cdot\vec{K})\ u_+(\vec{p})$$
where $\hat{p}$ is a unit vector in the direction of the boost, $K^i=\frac{i}{4}[\gamma^i,\gamma^0]=\frac{i}{2}\gamma^i\gamma^0$ is the boost matrix and $\eta=\sinh^{-1}(|\vec{p}|/m)$ is the rapidity of the fermion that moves with momentum $\vec{p}$. Eq. (\ref{1}), in matrix form, a boost along the $\hat{z}$ direction, brings the fermion wave-function to the form
$$u_+(\vec{p})=\pmatrix{\sqrt{E-|\vec{p}|}\\0\\\sqrt{E+|\vec{p}|}\\0}$$
which in the massless limit, $E\approx|\vec{p}|$, reduces to
$$u_+(\vec{p})=\sqrt{2E}\pmatrix{0\\0\\1\\0}\tag{2}\label{2}$$
In all, $u_+(\vec{p})$ in Eq. (\ref{2}) describes a massless fermion, whose direction of motion is alligned with its spin, and both are parallel to the $\hat{z}$ direction. It's four-momentum is given by $p^{\mu}=(E,0,0,E)$.

So, we know what does $u_+(\vec{p})$ describe. What if I wanted, for some reason, to choose a fermion wave function of the form
$$\tilde{u}_s(\vec{p})=\frac{\sqrt{2E}}{2}
\pmatrix{1\\0\\1\\0}$$
Then, I have the following two **questions**:
Can the chosen fermion wave-function correspond to a real fermion? If yes,

1. what will it's properties be?
2. how do I verify that it can correspond to a real fermion with the properties discussed in the first question?
3. is there a possibility for this fermion to be massless?

If there is no possibility for the wave-function to describe a fermion that can exist in nature, then why is there no such possibility?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The spinor doesn't necessarily describe anything. It's merely a construct in the formalism. It's an intermediate quantity allowing you to construct Lorentz covariant fields out of all the creation and annihilation operators. Reading Weinberg Vol1's first five chapters will resolve most philosophical questions about introductory QFT.

Comment: The spinor does indeed describe a fermion if the spinor satisfies the Dirac equation, no? I guess what I was asking was whether or not this criterion is sufficient or if there is something more?

Comment: You can certainly find some physical interpretation of spinors describing particles. But it basically won't work since spinor has negative energy which is unphysical for particle. You can free yourself from this endeavor once you read Weinberg.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much @Bababeluma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start by a silly little nitpick. Both Equations (1) and (2) are normalised so that $$|u_+|=\sqrt{2E}$$ and that means that the correctly normalised version of your guess of the state you want to consider should be
$$
\tilde u_s(\vec p)=\sqrt E
\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0
\end  {pmatrix}
$$
in order for the normalisation to be equivalent. We will continue by assuming that you stated this.

---

In the following, I will not endeavour to be exactly correct. The topic is abundantly covered properly in textbooks and you should refer to them if you want to get everything correct; and it should be within your abilities to derive these results yourself.

When you wrote down Equations (1) and (2), you are using the chiral representation. Note that in these equations, you have written down something that has the plane wave $e^{i(\vec p\cdot\vec r-Et)}$ part factored out and thrown away as understood to be not the interesting thing to consider for now. To consider things in comprehensive context, you really need to see that Equation (2) comes as a set of 4 basis vectors, namely
$$
\begin{align}
v_+&=\sqrt{2E}
\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0
\end  {pmatrix},&
v_-&=\sqrt{2E}
\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0
\end  {pmatrix},&
u_+&=\sqrt{2E}
\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0
\end  {pmatrix},&
u_-&=\sqrt{2E}
\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1
\end  {pmatrix}
\end  {align}
$$
with the interpretation that $u_\pm$ are +ve(-ve) chirality electrons and $v_\pm$ are +ve(-ve) chirality positrons.

Immediately, we have a simple understanding of your choice in the case of masslessness: it is the half-chance electron and half-chance positron, of +ve chirality.

In the case of massive fermions, you should be taking one step back. I am particularly unsure of the details here, but the set of four basis vectors should be looking like
$$
\begin{align}
v_+&=
\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{E+|\vec p|}\\0\\-\sqrt{E-|\vec p|}\\0
\end  {pmatrix},&
v_-&=
\begin{pmatrix}0\\\sqrt{E+|\vec p|}\\0\\-\sqrt{E-|\vec p|}
\end  {pmatrix},\\
u_+&=
\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{E-|\vec p|}\\0\\\sqrt{E+|\vec p|}\\0
\end  {pmatrix},&
u_-&=
\begin{pmatrix}0\\\sqrt{E-|\vec p|}\\0\\\sqrt{E+|\vec p|}
\end  {pmatrix}
\end  {align}
$$
The result will be that the thing you want to talk about will be some complicated linear combination of these states, but the general picture will be similar. One way to figure out exactly which linear combination it will be, is to find some way to make the combinations have only one non-zero component each, and then combine them to get what you want. It is just tedious maths that does nothing much useful to see.

Comment: Okay @naturallyInconsistent. Thank you so much for your answer. So, what you are essentially saying is that the spinors $\{u_+,\ u_-,\upsilon_+,\upsilon_-\}$, describing massless fermions with positive or negative helicity, and whose momentum is along the $\hat{z}$ direction, can be used as a basis for constructing more complicated spinors, which will correspond to superpositions of single particle states, yes?

Comment: Also, another minor comment: I couldn't help but to notice one mistake I have made. Eq. (2) from my question does not solve Dirac equation in momentum space. It actually solves a superposition of two Dirac equations, one for a fermion and another for an antifermion. Should this make my choice unphysical, in a sense??

Comment: Yes. And it is physical. Plane waves of massive Dirac fermions is the standard mass basis makes it clear that superpositions of electrons and positrons is the normal situation.

Comment: I am sorry @naturallyInconsistent, but I haven't understood your last statement. So, why is the fermion wave function that is a superposition between a state describing a fermion and a state describing an anti-fermion physical? And if they are physical, where can we find the particle described by such a state in nature?

Comment: I am saying that if you solved for the plane waves of Dirac fermions in the standard mass basis, which makes electrons, positrons and spin up and down particularly clear, you will see that any motion at all necessarily must be a superposition of fermion and anti-fermions. That means, if you just observe a moving electron, it is already in a physical state of such superpositions. There simply isn't much more to say about that.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much @naturallyInconsistent